# Selenium: delete contents from a textbox

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

Through selenium. how to delete contents from textbox.

I have to delete the last 2 characters from text box using selenium command.

Ex.ABCD to AB.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this -

```
selenium.type("text_box_object", "ABCD");
selenium.typeKeys("text_box_object", "\b");
selenium.typeKeys("text_box_object", "\b");
```

Comment: so "\b" is for backspace...  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

The **keyPress** event of selenium can be helpful:

```
selenium.sendKeys("text1", "ABCD");
selenium.sendKeys("text1", "\b");
selenium.sendKeys("text1", "\b");
```

This will Click **Backspace** key twice.

Answer (score 2):

Read the current value and store it as a variable. Then 'Type' out the value that you want in the target field (using a substring of the stored value).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Peter. This is good option,but I want to know is any selenium cmd available to delete the character from text box.

Answer (score 2):

For firefox, the backspace event works only if you setCursorPosition at the END of the text in the textarea, otherwise the typeKeys event will type at the begining of the text.

Answer (score 1):

Click onto it, hit end key and backspace twice

Comment: @ Orn I need to do it through selenium command .is there any way to recognize the End key, Backspace key trough selenium as I know keyPressNative() cmd will help? Thanks