# clear text field using DELETE or BACK SPACE key in webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to clear a text field using this action:

```
emailField.sendKeys("gmail.com");
emailField.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL,"a",Keys.DELETE);
```

In above code, the last line only selects the text, does not delete it, but if I separate the actions it works.

```
emailField.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL,"a");
emailField.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
```

Answer (score 29):

From the JavaDoc for `WebElement.clear()`:

> If this element is a text entry element, this will clear the value.
> Has no effect on other elements. Text entry elements are INPUT and
> TEXTAREA elements. Note that the events fired by this event may not be
> as you'd expect. In particular, we don't fire any keyboard or mouse
> events. If you want to ensure keyboard events are fired, consider
> using something like `sendKeys(CharSequence)` with the **backspace** key. To
> ensure you get a change event, consider following with a call to
> `sendKeys(CharSequence)` with the tab key.

Most likely you simply need to call:

```
emailField.sendKeys("gmail.com");
emailField.clear();
```

But if you need the clearing to be done via the keyboard for some reason, use `Keys.BACKSPACE`.

Comment: The backspace key is written as "\b" (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448257/selenium-delete-contents-from-a-textbox/22603085#22603085)

Answer (score 26):

keys.DELETE can not work to delete the input text,you should use keys.BACKSPACE.

```
emailField.sendKeys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
```

Answer (score 8):

From the JavaDoc for `Keys.chord`

> chord(java.lang.CharSequence... value) 
>   Simulate pressing many keys at once in a "chord".

You should be able to use

```
emailField.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"a",Keys.DELETE));
```

Comment: tks! `->sendKeys(array(WebDriverKeys::CONTROL,'a',WebDriverKeys::DELETE))->sendKeys(array($title)`

Answer (score 6):

Tested in chrome driver

```
WE.send_keys(' \b')
```

This will add space then delete it (backspace)

Answer (score 2):

I use in javascript and it's working fine:

```
await textBox.sendKeys(value);
await textBox.sendKeys(Key.BACK_SPACE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
emailField.sendKeys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
```

doesn't worked for me .

I used 'Key' instead of 'Keys'

```
emailField.sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACKSPACE)
```

Comment: What is the package of the Key class that you are using

Comment: I have used `protractor.Key.BACKSPACE`

Answer (score 0):

```html
emailField.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a",Keys.DELETE);
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP:

if you use php-webdriver (https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver) you must:

```
    use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverKeys AS Keys;
    .
    .
    .
    $this->driver->findElement(By::id('demo'))->sendKeys([Keys::BACKSPACE,'Any other text']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding another working C# example using the Google Chrome webdriver.

`SendKeys` only takes one parameter so created a string with the <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>. This code sequence will select the current text in the field then delete the text.

Code example:

```
var crtlA = Keys.Control + "a";

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/span/input")).SendKeys(crtlA); Wait(5000); // Select current text
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/span/input")).SendKeys(Keys.Delete); Wait(5000); // Clear current text
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/span/input")).SendKeys(newItemSku); Wait(5000); // Input SKU name
```

Answer (score -1):

```
1. in WebdriverIO, i tried to edit the text by clear text (which contains special charactes like @, +, _) in text field by below following step. Eventhough it was not successful.

example: text=> abc+1234@gmail.com

step1:browser.clearElement(selector);

step2:browser.execute(function () {
            document.querySelector(>>>Cssselector<<<).value="";
        });

step3: browser.doubleClick(selector);
       browser.keys("Delete");

step4: browser.click(selector);
       browser.keys(['Meta',a]);  
       browser.keys('Meta');   
       browser.keys('Delete');

Note: below step is resolved this issue.

var count= browser.getAttribute(selector, value).length;
for (var i=0;i<count;i++)
{
if (browser.getAttribute(selector, value)=='')
break;
}
else
{
browser.doubleClick(selector);
browser.keys("Delete");
}
browser.pause(200);
```

// it will clear your text field easily.

Note: 
You can add the new text now.